# Failed to determine the https port for redirect on Windows Server but not on PC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, https, windows-services, kestrel-http-server

I created an Asp.Net application and published it a server (Windows Server 2012 R2). It got the following message with the error of `Failed to determine the https port for redirect`.

```
PS C:\Users\xxx\Website> .\Blazor.exe
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\xxx\Websites\Portal1
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
```

However, it doesn't have the error if running on my PC?

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\WebSite\WebHub
```

Comment: It depends on how endpoints are configured, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration When there is not HTTPS endpoint, that error message is expected.

Answer (score -2):

I think your issue is with your appsettings.json file. Without specifying the line:

```
"https_port": 443,
```

to indicate which port is the SSL port, Blazor ASP.NET isn't sure where to route the traffic.

Comment: adding this alone causes redirect too many times error.